# Are computer science questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Mathematics and computer science go hand in hand, and often when I write code I stop and review and ask myself "Is there a better way of doing what I just did?"

This is a highly mathematical question. Is $X$ faster than $Y$. Are questions like that allowed? Or questions like posting / explaining your code and asking what is the runtime order?

Comment: Are you aware of cs.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I am now. Guess that answers my question :)

Comment: It might be on-topic here if by "faster" you mean algorithmic complexity/efficiency is the basis for answering.  In such cases the Question would likely be on-topic for CSTheory as well.  For numerical analysis Questions the scientific computation SE (confusingly branded Computational Science) might the best choice.

Comment: PSA: one can use site shortcut links in comments: `[cs.se]` becomes [cs.se], `[cstheory.se]` becomes [cstheory.se] and so on...

Comment: @hardmath: cstheory is for research level questions (like mathoverflow).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/computer-science/info

Comment: Just running your question through my Turing machine. Will get back to you when the tape stops.

Answer (score 12):

**Short answer:** Yes, CS questions are allowed, but only if they are mathematical in their focus.

**Long answer:** We are a math website.  Thus, the questions you ask must be mathematical in nature.  (Big surprise.)  If your CS question is *primarily* mathematical, we will accept it here.  If your CS question is asking about *implementation*, some *feature* of a specific language, etc., it will not be welcomed very nicely.

A good rule of thumb could be "Do I need to know how to program in language X in order to read or to answer this question?"  If yes, then it's off topic.  If no, then it's *probably* fine.

We don't like reading long listings of code; rather, please convert to pseudo-code before posting.  We also shouldn't need to know anything about computer architecture to answer your question (e.g. "is this algorithm faster, because it's accessing the L2 cache, vs this one that's working in memory?" is not good).

**Some history of this discussion:**

- [Can I ask this question about the effectiveness of a mathematical programming concept?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/can-i-ask-this-question-about-the-effectiveness-of-a-mathematical-programming-co)
- [Is theoretical computer science on topic?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/100/is-theoretical-computer-science-on-topic)
- [Computer science questions being closed as off-topic](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/computer-science-questions-being-closed-as-off-topic)
- [Do intro algorithm (computer science/complexity) questions belong here?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/do-intro-algorithm-computer-science-complexity-questions-belong-here)
- [Are algorithm questions acceptable](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/248/are-algorithm-questions-acceptable/254#254)

Comment: If you need to know how to program in language X to read and/or answer the question, the question is probably off-topic on [cs.se], too, and should be posted to [so] instead.

Comment: If you need to know how to program in language X then it isn't a computer science question to begin with.  "Computer science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes." (attribution disputed)

Comment: Their could be occasion to include code into an answer, given a certain type of question. For instance I think that it would be appropriate to include Lisp code to a question like this(if I were to expand my comment into a answer) :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851881/is-there-a-reason-behind-the-order-of-operations#comment1756797_851881 to illustrate the point about different syntaxes having different order of operations.